# Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, mysql-error-1068

Hi there this my code but I receive this error:

```
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined (SQL: alter table `wishlists` add primary key (`userId`, `productId`))
```

The code:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('wishlists', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
//            Foreign key for Users table
            $table->foreignId('userId');
            $table->foreign('userId')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

//            Foreign key for Products table
            $table->foreignId('productId');
            $table->foreign('productId')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->primary(['userId', 'productId']);

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

thanks

I've been search about it but couldn't find anything

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved!

I just had to remove `$table->id();`.
because the table is a relevant and don't need ID.